# What is the Dreamweaver Shortcut code for adding PHP tags around a string of HTML?

Tags: dreamweaver

Is it possible to write a php open and close tag around html tags in dreamweaver (as a shortcut), like it work with comments? 
Example:
before:

```
<label>Demotext</label>
```

after:

```
<?php echo '<label>Demotext</label>'?>
```

EDIT: I guess i explained wrong what I want: 
I have a lot of working html code. I have to pack every single line between `<?php` and `?>`. Thats why I asked if there is a Dreamweaver Shortcut for this. For example there is a Shortcut for comments (via right click and use HTML Comment). 

 
I hope now you understand me right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you searched this site page:
http://www.dreamweavershortcuts.co.uk/pages/allshortcuts.htm

Comment: You (and everybody) misunderstood me. I know both is the same, I just want a shortcut in dreamweaver. Well I edit my question to describe it better.

Comment: How about "What is the Dreamweaver Shortcut code for adding PHP tags around a string of HTML".  Oh yeah, and the only tag required is 'dreamweaver'

Comment: Thanks for input, I changed the headline. Sorry I am not a nativ speaker and for me it sound fine ;-)